# Instagram's Rest API "client_id=” not working / is removed or chanced?

Tags: rest, instagram, instagram-api, restful-authentication

I using this call url:

```
"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID".
```

I using client_id because my application type is windows service.

but this url throw this error:

```
{"meta": {"error_type": "OAuthAccessTokenException", "code": 400, "error_message": "The access_token provided is invalid."}}
```

what should I do?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

you have to authenticate using oauth2 and get `access_token` and use that to make API calls.

Here is more information:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

Comment: i use .net. my application type windows service and web request don't work because this call url: "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token"  have one more contain redirect. so web response haven't contain my web application source also auto redirect is open...